# Azure DevOps - SemVer of multiple applications

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, devops

I have a solution with multiple executable projects and I need to implement versioning. Major and minor numbers are stored in json files, patch numbers should be generated(incremented)
I wanted to use counter-function:

```
$[counter(variables['version.MajorMinor'], 0)]
```

So I came to something like this(just an example):

```
- job: GetVer
  displayName: 'Get Version'    
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Get version'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $arrayOfApps = @()
        foreach($file in Get-ChildItem $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) -Filter settings.json -Recurse | % { $_.DirectoryName })
        {
          $settingsJson = Get-Content ($file + '/settings.json') | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
          $arrayOfApps += $settingsJson
        }
        # So I have an array of objects (with a field called "Version") and it will be output variable
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MyArray;isOutput=true]$arrayOfApps"
    name: result
```

If I had just one version in the next job I could do something like that:

```
- job: SecondJob
  dependsOn: GetVer
  displayName: 'Try to increase version'
  variables:
    appVersion: $[ dependencies.GetVer.outputs['result.JUST_ONE_VERSION'] ]     
    patch: $[counter(variables['appVersion'], 0)]
```

but I have an array of versions: result.MyArray, so can't use the construction above. How to create appVersion and patch based on counter for each item in MyArray?
I wanted to use templates to solve the problem:

```
- template : azure-pipelines-mytemplate.yml
  parameters:
    Apps: MyArray
```

And in template I would:

```
- ${{ each foundApp in parameters.Apps}}:
- job: SecondJob
  dependsOn: GetVer
  displayName: 'Try to increase version'
  variables:
    appVersion: foundApp.Version
    patch: $[counter(variables['appVersion'], 0)]
```

I can't use templates because we can't send arrays with dynamic data to templates. "result.MyArray" is just a string, so this one:

```
- ${{ each foundApp in parameters.Apps}}:
```

will not work.

Is there a way to handle this? Of course I can generate the patch number by date, etc. but I wanted it to be incremented by +1.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what is impossible, can you elaborate on you last paragraph (maybe add a example too)

Comment: @Uuuuuumm, yep, I've updated the description